# Cakephp 2 errors on reporting level 0

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-2.3

I would like to show a custom error page when the reporting level is set to 0 and it is a **500 error** not a **404**. It seems I can't access the error message at all, outside of the default view.

I would like to set a custom layout outside of the normal error layouts. I know if I switch the reporting to level 1 or 2 then it works fine. I want this for production where it is set at 0 and not a 400 error. Is this possible?

`$error->getMessage()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q:** I would like to show a custom error page when the reporting level is set to 0 and it is a 500 error

**A:** You can edit the default error views `error400.ctp` and also **`error500.ctp`** in `/app/View/Errors/`

> **Q:** I would like to set a custom layout outside of the normal error layouts.

**A:** If you want to use another (custom) layout you can copy the file `CakeErrorController.php` from `/lib/Cake/Controller/` to `/app/Controller/` and add the following line in the function:

```php
function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
  $this->layout = 'your-layout-name'; // add this line in the function
  // ...
}
```

and add the [custom layout](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts) template file as usual in `/app/View/Layouts/`, e.g. `your-layout-name.ctp`

If you want to show data from your app in the error page/layout (eg generate the main menu from the database) you can add more custom code in your error controller as well, e.g.:

```
// Error controller in /app/Controller/CakeErrorController.php
class CakeErrorController extends AppController {
  public $uses = array('MenuCategory'); // load relevant table/model
  public function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
    $this->set('mainmenu', $this->MenuCategory->getMenu()); // or find() or whatever
    // ...
  }
}
```

> **Q:** How can I keep different error messages in production mode (debug level = 0)?

**A** According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html) *"ErrorHandler by default, displays errors when debug > 0, and logs errors when debug = 0."* The reason is e.g. that you should not show your public visitors (in production mode) an error message like "Missing Component", because this error is irrelevant and not useful for the visitor (so a 404/500 is responded). These kind of errors are only relevant for development and should be fixed before you go live in production mode.

If you want to change this behaviour you have to set up your own error handling as it is **exlained in the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-your-own-error-handler)**. Please also have a look at the explanation directly in the [CakePHP code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.10/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php#L28). You can also create your own [exeptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html) if necessary.

If you have problems in using/creating your own error handler, please start a new question on Stackoverflow with more details: What files have you created (e.g. **your error handler** and/or exceptions), how is your code looking like, what have you tried to solve the problem... and please give a clear example of what you want to achieve (e.g. in the comments below to the first version of my answer you are talking about special 500 errors - What is triggering these errors and what do you want to response instead of a 500 or what exactly do you want to change...)?

**An alternative solution** in some situations could also be something like this:

```php
// In your controller
public function moderator_view($id = null) {
  // Your error check, in this example the user role
  if ( $this->Auth->user('role') != 'moderator' ) {
    // Custom error message
    $this->Flash->custom('You are not a moderator.');
    // Redirect to your your special error page
    // In this example got to previous page
    return $this->redirect(
      $this->referer(
        // or go to a default page if no referrer is given
        array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'index', 'moderator' => false)
        )
      );
  }
  // else show moderator content...
}
```

Please also have a look at the [many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cakephp+custom+error) to custom error pages in CakePHP ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am looking for something slightly different. I would like for this to work when error mode is set to zero not one or higher. I have custom error handler already working above for when the error mode is set to 1 or higher. What I want is to intercept a non 404 request when the site is set in production mode or zero in the config file. As far as I know you can only trigger 404 errors when set to zero, which I understand.  I would just like to know if I can intercept that and show a slightly different error.

Comment: @digitalbart I don't understand your question - You can change the layout as well as the error message the way I described it... I think you can also change the http response code in your custom CakeErrorController, but that's not recommended as a "not found" should always be 404 and a general server error always a 500. What do you mean with "show a slightly different error"? What kind of error or error message or error response code are you talking about? Can you please add a clear example of the expacted result and a more detailed description in your question post?

Comment: If you have a 500 error when you are not in debug mode so level zero the default layout loads not an error layout. The error layout will load if you are in debug mode but I am not talking about that. So I want to show the user a friendly error message not a 500 error since we would be in production. You can't get to the error layout without being in debug mode, since this would be off there appears to be no way to catch this request. What happens then is the default layout loads with a 500 response in the header. I would like to catch this before it loads the default layout.

Comment: @digitalbart Sorry but I still don't get it... of course you can change the layout, for both 404 AND 500 errors, you can even use different layouts for the different error types! Also explained [here in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#exception-renderer) If the layout is not changing in your app after you customized it in the CakeErrorController or directly in the error view templates please add the code of your customised controller/view, maybe there is another problem in the code that is causing Cake to use the wrong layout in production mode...

Comment: If the cake config is set to zero doesn't it suppress error messages, except 404 errors. So I want to get around that if possible.

Comment: Wow this is great I appreciate all your help. :-)

Comment: You can put `$this->layout = 'your-layout-name';` in a view file btw.